# Quip Live Apps - During the publishing it fail because can't find dist/app.js file

Tags: liveapps

I'm new to Quip development.
Start following the tutorial.
The init phase fails at the last step because it doesn't create the dist/app.js file.
Here is the message I got.

```
WARNING: the following files were defined in your manifest, but were not found.
This bundle may be incomplete, you should include these files or remove them from your manifest.
=== js_files ===
dist/app.js
Not Found
Publishing failed
```

Any clue? Any help will be very much welcomed.
Many thanks in advance.
Claudio.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a quip live app, don't install the latest version of the node js just downgrade it to node version 14 or lesser than that not greater than 14.
Because quip doesn't support greater than node js 14 version.